# Processing file upload in grails controller

Tags: jquery, grails

Im trying to implement this plugin:https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload , in my grails web-app.
I currently have the barebones required, but am unsure as to how I should process the information in the backend i.e: do the actual uploading.

```
  <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" >
  <script>
      $(function () {
            var url ="${createLink(controller: 'backDoor', action: 'uploadFile')}"
          $('#fileupload').fileupload({
              url: url,
              dataType: 'json',
              done: function (e, data) {
                  $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                      $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                  });
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Now in my grails controller: backdoor/uploadFile how can I save the file to say the C: drive ?